# Do people use MIT's app inventor for professional android apps?

Tags: app-inventor

My understanding of the tool is that it helps people learn about programming by making it easy to create android apps. Is it just for educational purposes or can you actually build a commercial quality app with it?

I know the backend of a professional app would have to be written using something else but is it good enough to create an entire front end android app?

If people are making real apps with it, what are some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can

To find some examples do the following:
1. search the App Inventor forums [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/programming-with-app-inventor/professional$20app) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/mitappinventortest/ai-apps---lets-see-what-you-can-do)
2. [search Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=id=appinventor&c=apps&hl=en)
3. [take a look at the App Inventor Classic App Gallery thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appinventor/Pf-_1qkaNEY%5B1-25-false%5D)
4. [ask in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest)